# функция transform

Tags: css3

доброго времени суток! адаптирую модальное окно, пытаюсь отцентрировать окно. поискала, пишут можно с помощью функции transform. прописываю главному блоку функция transform: translate(-50%, -50%) - не воспринимает браузер данную функцию. не понимаю в чем дело. есть варианты? может другой способ есть? спасибо)

Comment: `margin: auto;`

Comment: Какой браузер (и версия)? Может префиксы помогут?

Comment: margin тоже не реагирует((( дело в том, что я не сама верстала модальное окно, я его только адаптирую. браузер chrome

Comment: position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

Comment: делаю тоже самое, не выходит(

Comment: я прописываю: position: fixed; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); - transform не работает

Answer (score 1):

Пример `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` работает

```css
.modal {
    padding: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">modal</div>
```

Одной из причин может быть использование у родителя `-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0)`, тогда `position:fixed` не работает

```css
body{
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);
}
.modal {
    padding: 100px;
    background: #ccc;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal">modal</div>
```